# Get PDF file page count in Dart

Tags: dart, pdf

In Dart, how to get number of pages of PDF document loaded from `File`, withoud actualy displaying it or using any `Widget` for Flutter?

Preferably by using https://pub.dev/packages/pdf package.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this too. If you're targeting Android only, this plugin should do the trick, https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_bitmaps.